# CheckboxPreference not unchecking or going to false

Tags: android, checkbox, preference

i am currently doing an android security application and im trying to uncheck a CheckboxPreferences after certain conditions have been made so im trying to uncheck the checkbox by doing this

Activity:

```
            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("isPhysicalTheftEnabled", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
            ed.putBoolean("isPhysicalTheftEnabled", false);
            ed.commit();
```

preferences.xml

```
<CheckBoxPreference
            android:id="@+id/isPhysicalTheftEnabled"
            android:key="isPhysicalTheftEnabled"
            android:title="Enable Physical Theft Protection"
            android:summary="Select to enable the Physical Theft Protection"
            android:defaultValue="false"/>
<Preference android:key="physicaltheft" android:title="Set Physical Theft Protection Password" android:dependency="isPhysicalTheftEnabled"></Preference>
```

But the CheckBoxPreference doesn't get unchecked even after i do the ed.commit(); any idea why that would happen?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you open preference file called "isPhysicalTheftEnabled", then you write false TO THIS FILE. You don't update user-visible settings, only save value called 'isPhysicalTheftEnabled' to file with the same name. To have your layout updated you need to implement [onPreferenceChange](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) in your PreferenceActivity, or Fragment, ex.

```
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "NewValue: " + newValue.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: No by default it is false, so i will enable it and i want it to be false again after i do some functions

Comment: So what you want is: restoring settings from file to layout, after someone launches it later again?

Comment: No, i just want to uncheck that CheckboxPreference to be false after certain function is executed

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
        SharedPreferences sp = getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

or

```
        SharedPreferences sp = getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below:

```
cbxxx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                Editor edit = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                        youractivity.this).edit();
                if (isChecked) {
                    edit.putBoolean("isPhysicalTheftEnabled", true);
                } else {
                    edit.putBoolean("isPhysicalTheftEnabled", false);
                }
                edit.commit();
            }
        });
```

and if you want to get the above value:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = preferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
if(prefs.getBoolean("isPhysicalTheftEnabled", false)){
}
```